# Show and hide EditText on button click

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imagebutton

I have this `ImageButton` that makes a `EditText` visible:

```
final ImageButton k = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSearchButton);
k.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CallActivity.this, R.anim.search_jump);
        k.startAnimation(anim);

        mySearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        mySearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation searchAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CallActivity.this, R.anim.push_left_in);
        mySearchView.startAnimation(searchAnim);

    }
});
```

When the `ImageButton` is clicked the `EditText` slides in from right to left, and then when the `ImageButton` is clicked again the `EditText` should slide out again, and hiding it, how could i create this effect?

Comment: You can use a togglebutton for that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by checking that the `EditText` is visible or not:

```
if(mySearchView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
    mySearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    mySearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToggleButton like this

```
ToggleButton b = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

// attach an OnClickListener
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    if(((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
    // handle toggle on
} else {
   // handle toggle off
} 
});
```

And set the images as background for togglebuttons